# Find document in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Looking for a way to find a document registered in Sharepoint. I can find document in a documet library or list by following code.

```
SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite(_serverUrl);
SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.OpenWeb();
SPList oSPList;
SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection;
oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists["Listname"];
SPListItem listItem = null;
listItem = oSPList.GetItemByUniqueId(new Guid(spGuid));
```

But do i need to iterate trough all list if i dont know in which list the document is registered or is there a more efficient way.

Comment: Do you know the URL of the document?

Answer (score 1):

If the *UniqueId* is the only information you have then you have to create a `SPSiteDataQuery` to retrieve the URL of the document:

```
SPWeb web = // ...

SPSiteDataQuery q = new SPSiteDataQuery();            
q.Query = String.Format(
            "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='UniqueId' /><Value Type='Lookup'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", 
             spGuid);
q.Lists = "<Lists BaseType="1" />";  // restrict to document libraries   
q.RowLimit = 1;
// q.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection' />"; add to broaden the search on the whole site collection
q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl' />";

DataTable tbl = web.GetSiteData(q);

if (tbl.Rows.Count == 0) throw new FileNotFoundException(...);

return tbl.Rows[0]["EncodedAbsUrl"];
```

Then you can load the `SPFile` (the document) with `SPWeb.GetFile(string)`. If you just need the `SPListItem` you can access this via `SPFile.Item`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know in what list the document is placed you will need to iterate over the available SPList objects from the SPWeb.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Think i found a solution. If i know guid of document i can do ....fileItem = oSPWeb.GetFile(new Guid(spGuid)); where spGuid is string guid

Comment: Yeah, that would be a better solution if you have the guid :)

Comment: you should have a look at this wonderful feature http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/04/document-id-feature/ http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-HA101790471.aspx